# Error check for character when reading in integers in C

Tags: c, error-checking

For my programming class I've written a program to calculate the sum of divisors. So I've gotten to my final part which is error checking, which I am having a problem with if I read a character in. I have searched on S.O. earlier,as well as tried to figure something out, and couldn't find a solution that works for endless negative numbers until 100.

When I hit a character it sets it to 0 and just goes to the end, where I want it to exit once it reads it in

```
int main (void){
int userIN=0;
int i = 0;
int next = 0;
int temp= 105;
int cycle;
puts("Enter up to 10 integers less than or equal to 100");
while(scanf("%d ", &userIN) !=EOF && (i < 10))
{
  if(userIN > 100){
   printf("Invalid Input\n");
   exit(1);  
  }
  else if(userIN < 100)
  {
```

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT: The program is cycling through correctly, My Issue is error checking for a character being entered not anything with the code itself

Comment: That doesn't look like your complete code

Comment: Its not my complete code,this is the place where I'm having the problem...reading in &userIN as an integer

User Enters a Character

Im only error checking for Integers greater than 100

I dont want to add my entire code because it is homework and don't want someone else to copy it

Comment: are you initializing i to zero?

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` returns a value other than `EOF` if it cannot read the values specified by the format string (e.g. with `%d`, it encounters data like `foo`).  You can check for that.    The caveat is that it does not read the offending data from `stdin`, so it will still be there to affect the next call of `scanf()` - which can result in an infinite loop (`scanf()` reporting an error, call `scanf()` again, it encounters the same input so reports the same error).

You are probably better off reading a whole line of input, using `fgets()`.  Then check the input manually or use `sscanf()` (note the additional `s` in the name).  The advantage of such an approach is that it is easier to avoid an infinite loop on unexpected user input.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop while `i` is less than 10. The first if will see if scanf failed. If so the input buffer is cleared and the while loop tries again. If EOF is captured, then `exit`. If scanf is successful, the input is compared to 100 and if in range, the while loop counter is incremented.
Declare `int ch = 0;`

```
while ( i < 10) {
    printf("Enter %d of 10 integers. (less than or equal to 100)\n", i + 1);
    if(scanf(" %d", &userIN) != 1)
    {
        while ( ( ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
            //clear input buffer
        }
        if ( ch == EOF) {
            exit ( 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(userIN > 100){
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
        }
        else
        {
            i++;// good input advance to the next input
            printf("Valid");
        }
    }
}
```